# Update remote refs after bundling

Tags: git

I have a situation where I need to use a repository on a remote machine with no direct access to the upstream repository. I plan to use bundles to push changes back periodically by creating a bundle from the known location of origin/develop to the current HEAD.

This works well to put changes back to the upstream repository, but I'm uncertain how to update the reference to origin/develop in the offline repository once this has been done. I thought I could use a bundle in the other direction but when I try to apply it, it does nothing useful:

```
$ git fetch ../remote-sync.bundle                
From ../remote-sync.bundle
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
$ git log --oneline --all --graph -n3                 
* 72293fb (develop) Implement C library function memchr
* 2c97010 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/develop, origin/HEAD) Test code attempt #1
```

In the upstream repository, 72293fb is now the head of develop, but here it is still marked as being at 2c97010 after applying the bundle.

I tried some branch parameters passed to fetch - like `git fetch remote-sync.bundle origin/develop` but it failed since it knows nothing about that ref.

I haven't really used git for more than simple things like pushing to github for one-man projects occasionally before now so my understanding of fetch is somewhat limited.

Thanks,

Comment: Consider [setting up access to the repository using an SSH tunnel](https://www.systutorials.com/5466/git-through-ssh-tunnel-as-proxy/) instead. It's far more convenient. Otherwise unless the repo is very large it might be simpler to download the whole repo to a machine which has repo access, bring it up to date normally, and upload it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the upstream repository, 72293fb is now the head of develop, but here it is still marked as being at 2c97010 after applying the bundle.

A fetch would not change your current HEAD, it would only update remote tracking branches or remote references.

After your fetch, you can reset your HEAD to any commit you want, or do instead

```
git pull ../remote-sync.bundle master
```